# Why does this singleton implementation use a private class (C++)?

Tags: c++, class, singleton

So I am working with some new code from a supplier's app, and I observed that for one of their libraries, they are using a Singleton pattern. There they use a `Helper` to instantiate the singleton. Why is that necessary?

library header file:

```
Class LibExample {

public:
    static LibExample* getInstance();

private:
    class Helper {
    public:
        Helper() {
            libExampleInstance = new LibExample();
        }
        ~Helper() {
            delete libExampleInstance;
        }

        LibExample* libExampleInstance;
     };

    static LibExample* m_instance;

    LibExample();
    virtual ~LibExample();
    LibExample (const LibExample& ) {};
    LibExample& operator=(const LibExample&) {
        return *(LibExample::getInstance());
    }
};
```

In the .cpp file:

```
LibExample* LibExample::m_instance = NULL;

LibExample* LibExample::getInstance() {
    static Helper instance;
    if(m_instance == NULL) {
        m_instance = instance.libExampleInstance;
        int ret = m_instance->init();
        if(ret < 0) {
           m_instance = NULL;
        }
    }
    return m_instance;
}
```

Comment: I imagine : To have the ability to null the instance `m_instance` without having to deallocate/reallocate memory each time a failed `init` is done. What I don't understand is why they would alloc memory on the heap instead of on the stack if it doesn't involve polymorphism.

Comment: @ChrisR., `What I don't understand is why they would alloc memory on the heap instead of on the stack` I don't know about this particular case, but in some cases (i.e. when you work with embedded), the stack size may be limited so much that instances of large enough objects simply will not fit.

Answer (score 2):

> There they use a 'Helper' to instantiate the singleton. Why is that necessary?

It is not. The `Helper` may be used here to allows the `m_instance == NULL` test, and call `init` when first using `getInstance`, but `init` could have been run in `LibExample` constructor as well. There may be an obscure reason but IMHO this design is just overcomplicated.

You could have:

```
Class LibExample {

public:
    static LibExample* getInstance();

private:
    LibExample();
    virtual ~LibExample();
    LibExample (const LibExample& ) {};
    LibExample& operator=(const LibExample&) {
        return *(LibExample::getInstance());
    }
};

LibExample* LibExample::getInstance() {
    static LibExample instance;
    static LibExample* p_instance = NULL;
    if(p_instance == NULL) {
        int ret = instance.init();
        if(ret >= 0) {
            p_instance = &instance;
        }
    }
    return p_instance;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

As pointed by @SingerOfTheFall in the comments:

> I think this is done to implement some kind of a late initialization: if `init()` fails the first time, the singleton itself doesn't need to be re-constructed, and it will try to re-initialize itself the next time the instance is called.

Still `Helper` is not necessary: I modified my code accordingly.

Comment: I think this is done to implement some kind of a late initialization: if `init()` fails the first time, the singleton itself doesn't need to be re-constructed, and it will try to re-initialize itself the next time the instance is called.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall you're right, I integrated this in my answer

Comment: I think the new code may still have some problem, like multiple thread will call `init`, thus a lock can't be avoided.

Comment: @Danh yes but, correct me if I'm wrong, the `Helper` class doesn't change this. This should be fixed using a mutex(?)

Comment: Yes, I think mutex should be used in `init`, but I think it defeats the purpose of static local object. Anyway, I found this implementation is over-complicated, I think a single `bool` value should be enough